# How to delete struct object in a vector<struct>?

Tags: smart-contract, development

I thought it would be good idea to store a object of struct in a vector because I have seen it in a tutorial [Tutorial](https://infinitexlabs.com/eos-development-tutorial-part-2/) but now I have a problem if I want to remove it from the vector. I want to make addressbook like contract.

I tried:

- delete itr_address->book[i] => because of a const variable in the struct this is not working
- itr_address->book.erase(itr_address->book.begin()+1) => some other error because of const

Comment: I do not know exactly what you're going to do. Please explain based on the contents of the tutorial.

Comment: In the tutorial you create a struct item. Later you create vector<item> in player struct. Then he shows how to add items to player:  

player.inventory.push_back(item{
            purchased_item.item_id,
            purchased_item.name,
            purchased_item.power,
            purchased_item.health,
            purchased_item.ability,
            purchased_item.level_up
        });

now I tried to do the same thing for a test addressbook. But when i want to delete the item from the vector i get there errors because of const in the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the item from the player's inventory and modify the player using players.modify.

players.modify(iterator, account, [&](auto& player) { 
    player.inventory.erase(i);
});

Comment: thx no more errors